# Error selecting image: "[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am unable to resolve the following error when selecting an image from an image library:

**[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error**

This is my code:

```
-(void)touchPhoto:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
{

NSLog(@"Photo touched");

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[picker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

NSLog(@"Presenting imagePicker");
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)info{



NSLog(@"did finish");
//WHEN YOU HAVE FINISHED PICKING FROM LIBRARY OR CAMERA

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


//save the image added


UIImage *secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iconImageClear.png"];

NSData *imgData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);
NSData *imgData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(secondImage);

BOOL isCompare =  [imgData1 isEqual:imgData2];
if(isCompare)
{
    NSLog(@"Image View contains image.png");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Image View doesn't contains image.png");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Photos"];

    NSString *photoPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", dataPath, self.mealTitleTextfield.text,self.mealDescriptionTextfield.text];



    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image, 1.0);
    [data writeToFile:photoPath atomically:YES];

}



}
```

**Debug output:**

2016-12-27 23:12:26.293 Meal Planner[3092:118535] Photo touched
2016-12-27 23:12:26.313 Meal Planner[3092:118535] Presenting imagePicker
2016-12-27 23:12:29.668255 Meal Planner[3092:118535] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
2016-12-27 23:12:31.682 Meal Planner[3092:118535] did finish

I don't normally post as there is usually an answer but I cannot seem to find one for this..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your code otherwise do what you want?  You can get all sorts of errors and warnings in the console that don't impact your app,operation?

Comment: No, it doesn't do as required (it did work until i upgraded my xcode and ios). After an image is selected, an imageview should then contain the image and the selected image should be saved to the doc directory - neither of this happens :(

Comment: You can ignore the error. You should single step through your code and see what is happening. Is the `else` code executing?